# @SendTo not working in JMS (ActiveMQ integration) with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms

I am facing a weird issue, I am not able to send my messages to a `demoQueue` in ActiveMQ using only @SendTo("demoQueue") annotation, I have tried following, I managed to send a message to the queue using `JmsTemplate` but I also read in a blog that @SendTo will do this for you.

Below is the code that I tried, the version that isn't working.

```
@Component
public class ProducerTask {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerTask.class);
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/3 * * * *")
    @SendTo("demoQueue")
    public String pushToQueue() {
        String str = "Running scheduled task >> " + ZonedDateTime.now();
        LOG.info(str);
        return str;
    }
}
```

The version with `JmsTemplate` that is working fine.

```
@Component
public class ProducerTask {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerTask.class);

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/3 * * * *")
    public String pushToQueue() {
        String str = "Running scheduled task >> " + ZonedDateTime.now();
        LOG.info(str);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("demoQueue");
        jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage(str);
            }
        });
        // TODO put the logic for consuming in different bean and inject here and call that method here.
        return str;
    }
}
```

Please explain, I am confused here. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `@SendTo` annotation as part of any method. It works within the context of a `@JmsListener` (or another listener, like `@KafkaListener`), see this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/30/spring-4-1-s-upcoming-jms-improvements).

Comment: I am confused as they have used two different queue names with `@JmsListener` and `@SendTo`, from what I understood `@JmsListener` tries to read the message from the queue and `@SendTo` sends the message back to the queue as an acknowledgment, is this correct? Is there a way I can send the message directly to queue (not as an acknowledgment) using the same annotation?

Comment: The `@SentTo` behaviour is described here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-annotated-response It is only used within the context of a message reply. To send a message, you still have to use your `jmsTemplate`. So no, you can't.

Comment: @AlexB, I just want to make sure, it is impossible to use ```@SendToUser``` with any ```@Listener```. Is that correct?